# ASP.NET after postbackurl losing session

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I'm using a session, and I redirect to a page I lose my session.
I know I can give the redirect a false return, so it keeps the session.
But now I fill a button after an event, so it redirects aswell to a page with a postbackurl like this:

```
string btn_plaats = reader["Gmsplaats"].ToString();

ImageButton knop = (ImageButton)this.FindControl(btn_plaats);
knop.ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + reader["Gamenaam"] + ".png";
knop.PostBackUrl = "~/Games/" + reader["Gamenaam"] + ".aspx";
knop.OnClientClick = "";
```

Now I do lose my session because it doesnt have a false return value, How can I give the postbackurl a false return value?
(the code is in C# code behind used with access database)

Comment: How are you saving your Session object?

Comment: By doing this: conn.Open();
                        Session["Gebruikersnaam"] = TextBox1.Text;
                        result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
In my login page

Comment: What session state mode are you using? (InProc, StateServer, SQLServer, etc)